# How to extract digits 12345 into different variables

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How to extract the close value and store it in Variable ? something similar to excel function LEFT/RIGHT
example if close price is 123
want to extract it into
`x = left(1) = 1 y = left(2:1) = 2 z  = right(1) 3`

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function using `/` and the modulo operator.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

f_get_digit(num, digit) =>
    int temp = num
    int ret_val = na

    if (num == 0)
        ret_val := 0
    else
        cnt = 0
        while (temp != 0)
            dig = temp % 10
            temp := int(temp / 10)
            cnt := cnt + 1

            if (cnt == digit)
                ret_val := dig
                break
    ret_val

my_num = 12345

test1 = f_get_digit(my_num, 0)
test2 = f_get_digit(my_num, 1)
test3 = f_get_digit(my_num, 2)
test4 = f_get_digit(my_num, 3)
test5 = f_get_digit(my_num, 4)
test6 = f_get_digit(my_num, 5)
test7 = f_get_digit(my_num, 6)

s = "Number: " + str.tostring(my_num) + "\n"
s := s + "Digit 0: " + str.tostring(test1) + "\n"
s := s + "Digit 1: " + str.tostring(test2) + "\n"
s := s + "Digit 2: " + str.tostring(test3) + "\n"
s := s + "Digit 3: " + str.tostring(test4) + "\n"
s := s + "Digit 4: " + str.tostring(test5) + "\n"
s := s + "Digit 5: " + str.tostring(test6) + "\n"
s := s + "Digit 6: " + str.tostring(test7)

if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(bar_index, low, s, textcolor=color.white, textalign=text.align_left)
```

[image]

Comment: Eish ...such big code ..i taught would be easy like left/right function in EXCEL ...thanks a lot @vitruvius ..